'list' object has no attribute 'destroy'. Tkinter destroy, forget function
So in summary my code is making a changeable amount of Entry's and Labels.
There is a part of this code that is important.
for i in range(10):
 
 for z in range(5):
  
  entry_dict = {}
  entry_dict[f'grid-{i}-{z}'] = [f'grid-{i}-{z}']
  fake_label = {}
  fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'] = [f'grid-{i}-{z}']
  if z == 0:
     random_tran = random.choice(tran_pre)
     entry_dict[f'grid-{i}-{z}'] = ctk.CTkEntry(data, textvariable=var_num[f'transaction_{i}'],           
     height=60, width = 90, bg_color = 'grey18')
     

     fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'] = ctk.CTkLabel(data, text = random_tran, height=60, width = 90,  
     bg_color = 'grey18') 

     fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'].bind('<Button>', lambda event: disapear(fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'])) 

     entry_dict[f'grid-{i}-{z}'].place(x=iks, y=igrek)
     fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'].place(x=iks, y=igrek)
     iks = iks + 95
  

Im using a dict to set their names and everything works fine until i wont Labels to be deleted when clicked. Its this line of code
fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}'].bind('<Button>', lambda event: disapear(fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}']))

def disapear(Widget_):
   
   Widget_.destroy()

But i got en error here:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'destroy'
I don't understand why I can use the 'place' function with a dict named label, but I can't forget it or destroy it. And why is a list named in error while I'm using a dict?
I tried using normal lambda, forget_palce function, but I got no idea why this is even happening.

Sidenote: strongly suggest using more than one space for indentation.

Each time through the loop you're clearing out the dictionaries.  That's not likely to be correct.

At the time that disappear() actually gets called, the value of i will be 9, and z will be 4 - in other words, the final values that are assigned by your for loops.  The corresponding element in fake_label is the list ["grid-9-4"] (thus the error); it's not one of the elements that was replaced with an actual widget.  You need to capture the values at the moment the lambda is defined: one way to do this is lambda event, i=i, z=z: disapear(fake_label[f'grid-{i}-{z}']) (relying on the fact that default parameters are evaluated at definition time).

Okey that makes sense and solved the problem, yeah my bad i should have seen that, thanks for quick help!
